# How to get HTML cell Value Without Click Event I need to get Cell value Directly

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

How to get HTML cell Value Without Click Event I need to get Cell value Directly without Any Alert Functions

Html

```
<table runat="server" id="Rightbar" class="table"> <tr><th>Income</th><td id="TableIncome" runat="server">$1230</td></tr> <tr><th>Reimbursement</th><td id="TableReimbursement" alert="Total()" runat="server">$1230</td></tr> <tr><th>Expenses</th><td id="TableExpenses" alert="Total()" runat="server" class="text-danger">$1230</td></tr> <tr class="info"><th>Net Total</th><td runat="server" id="NetTotal">$1230</td></tr> </table>
```

Javascript

```
var txt1 = document.getElementById("TableReimbursement"); 
var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td"); alert(Cells[0].innerText); 
alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML); 
var Value = document.getElementById("Rightbar").rows[0].cells.namedItem("TableIncome").inner‌​HTML
```

Comment: show me what u tried so far ?

Comment: //var txt1 = document.getElementById("TableReimbursement");
              //var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
              //alert(Cells[0].innerText);
             
            
                  alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML);
           var Value = document.getElementById("Rightbar").rows[0].cells.namedItem("TableIncome").innerHTML

Comment: paste ur html code also in ur question

Comment: <table runat="server" id="Rightbar"  class="table">
   <tr><th>Income</th><td id="TableIncome"  runat="server">$1230</td></tr>
   <tr><th>Reimbursement</th><td id="TableReimbursement" alert="Total()"  runat="server">$1230</td></tr>
   <tr><th>Expenses</th><td id="TableExpenses" alert="Total()"  runat="server" class="text-danger">$1230</td></tr>
   <tr class="info"><th>Net Total</th><td runat="server"  id="NetTotal">$1230</td></tr>
   
   
   </table>

Comment: so which value you need to get spefic?

Comment: you need to get all table values ?

Comment: I need to get any 1  Vale With Id or By Cells[n]

Comment: i dont understand what ur expected result ?

Comment: In My Asp.NET Application I have an HTML Table 

I need to get the Particular Cell Value Using java Script of Else Jquery Without Using Alert or Click Functions

Comment: im asking youre expected result like u need to get this `Income` value from table ?

Comment: <td id="TableIncome" runat="server">$1230</td>

I need to get the Above Mentioned Cell Value i.e TD value of Table Income whose id is "tableIncome"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m696sgju/ check this may be u need this

Comment: Thanks for your Help I need to Get Value Without Click Event Is it Possible

Comment: yes on page load the value comes right ?

Comment: Thanks Boss

I need to change the cell value of Net Total when Income changes How It will be possible 
last help from your Side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/m696sgju/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Label -'+$('#Rightbar tr th:first').html()); 
    alert('Value -'+$('#Rightbar tr td:first').html()); 
});
```